# Sanitization of character set

Tags: penetration-test, appsec, vulnerability

I have come across a scenario where the character set not being sanitized / verified.

What is the security implication by not confirming the expected character set? Can you also provide a practical example please to illustrate the security implications?

Assume character set should be UTF-8.

Comment: I doubt to have the appropriate knowledge to answer your question. On the other hand, in programming in general, i.e. not specific to crypto, a program may under circumstances essentially depend on the character set that is assumed by the programmer, namely each character c of an user input string has a value ord(c) of it in the character set and the program behaves corresponding to such values. If these values get wrong because the user somehow employs a different character set, I suppose it is understandable that the program would work wrongly.

Answer (score 2):

[Unicode Technical Report #36](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr36/) has some examples. In your case exploits that make use of [ill-formed byte subsequences](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr36/#Ill-Formed_Subsequences) may be of interest.